# Gitea Jenkins plugin: discovering branches to build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, multibranch-pipeline, gitea

Gitea [recommends](https://gitea.com/gitea/awesome-gitea/src/branch/master/README.md#user-content-devops) a separate [Gitea Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitea-plugin) for Jenkins. I'm puzzled why two identical builds are triggered when a PR is created.

I'm trying to achieve the following:

- Without a PR, a push to a branch should NOT trigger a build
- Every time a PR is requested in Gitea, a build is triggered for the PR.
- If a new revision pushed to the branch for which a PR is created, another check build should be triggered

It's kinda working... But for some reasons two builds are created. Could someone please explain, what are these **pipeline/head** and **pipeline/pr-master** builds, and why there are two of them?

[image]

Here is the relevant part of my Jenkins configuration. I understand that this selection is a "legacy" one, however it's the only one that allows me to build only on PR. If I select the "recommended" one, then every push triggers a build, which is not what I want.
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question. Awwww what a silly sausage I am. The only thing that needed to be done was removing the "Discover branches" behaviour. And, naturally, it stops discovering "just branches" :) For some reasons I did not realise I can remove the default behaviours.

[image]